# Fixing project GUIDs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a solution file that's become 'unstuck' from the projects it references, so that the project GUID references in the .sln point to incorrect GUIDs for the projects that they reference, and this problem persists into several of the projects themselves.

1) Is there an automated tool for fixing this? Anyone who's dealt with this issue knows that the most infuriating part is that it still builds in visual studio, while msbuild bombs out - I assume that this means that the necessary information is there, and could be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about automatic tools, but I've had this before and the manual fix of going into the .sln file and changing the GUID was simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

The solution file's just a text file.  I don't know if there's an automated tool to fix it, but you can do it yourself in notepad or write a simple script that uses regexes to do it.